# htaccess - Deny access to certain urls but allow others

Tags: apache, .htaccess, feed, ddos

I'm having a DDoS attack to my wordpress site. Thousands of request to any urls followed by /feed!
So I would add a rule on htaccess to to block any request contain "/feed" BUT I need to allow some exceptions that I really cannot block:
1. mysite.com/feed (the main rss feed)
2. mysite.com/category/feed (some specific category feed I use to share)

Is it possible to build a rule like this?

Tnx in advance

Comment: Can you place your full .htaccess in question

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

##1##
RewriteRule ^(feed|category/feed)/?$ - [L]
##2##
RewriteRule ^.*feed.*$ - [F,L]
```

The first rule matches requests
/feed or /category/feed and lets them pass untouched. (no rewriting)

The second rule checks if the the requested uri has "/feed" anywhere in the string then forbid the request.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I'm using FeedBurner as filter, so I let it pass and block others

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !FeedBurner
RewriteRule feed - [R=403]`

Now I would like to implement an ELSE statement to redirect to feedburner all non-feedburner accessing to /feed

1. FeedBurner -> get access to the feed
2. /feed redirect to FeedBurner
3. Any other access containing /feed is forbidden